# CSV Validation library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, validation, csv

Does anybody knows of a .NET library to validate csv files, similar to https://github.com/frictionlessdata/goodtables-py.
After a google search I haven't found anything near enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See: [Built in .Net CSV Parser](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/). A *parser* not really a *validator*, and it seems like it doesn't handle multiline fields, but maybe a start.

Comment: Parsing the file is a start but not the problem I'm trying to solve. I want a library that given a set of rules would tell me if the file is valid or not. That's exactly what goodtables does, but I need it to be in .NET and I don't want to implement it myself.

Comment: Also not a "real" answer, but: an XSD is a very good way to define the structure of a text document (not just xml). With the [xsd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe), you can automatically create classes from that. Now you would "just" need to read the CSV into that class structure, serialize the data (in memory?) and then [validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-schema-xsd-validation-with-xmlschemaset) that against the XSD. Not *quite* out-of-the-box, but also not too much to implement yourself.

Comment: Hi Sergio, did you find what you were looking for? I have similar requirement and looking for the same type of tools. You can look at Fluent.Validation (you need to check the csv structure first and load data to collection of DTOs, and no config file) or MS Enterprise Library application validation block (there is also .net standard port on github) it has config files but still need to load data to collection of DTOs. For me these libs are not good, maybe you have something different?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library for your needs

Couple of ways you can validate CSV file

```
bool isValid = true;
using (var cr = new ChoCSVReader("sample.csv")
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    .WithField("firstName")
    .WithField("lastName")
    .WithField("salary", fieldType: typeof(double))
    .Setup(c => c.RecordLoadError += (o, e) => { isValid = false; e.Handled = true; })
    .Configure(c => c.ErrorMode = ChoErrorMode.ReportAndContinue)
)
{
    foreach (var x in cr)
        Console.WriteLine(ChoUtility.ToStringEx(x));
}
Console.WriteLine(isValid);
```

On the next release, you can do the validation even simpler

```
using (var cr = new ChoCSVReader("sample.csv")
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    .WithField("firstName")
    .WithField("lastName")
    .WithField("salary", fieldType: typeof(double))
)
{
    foreach (var x in cr)
        Console.WriteLine(ChoUtility.ToStringEx(x));

    Console.WriteLine(cr.IsValid);
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Comment: This looks more like it, thanks. However, in you example you have to add the validation rules one by one per column, if I go with you library I would still need to map from my validation template to your in line rules definition. Are you planning to add this functionality in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

There is a .Net Framework assembly you can use below and look for type **TextFieldParser**. But still you will have to write some simple code

> Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly

```
    using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
...
var path = @"C:\CsvFile.csv";
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");

    string[] line;
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        try
        {
            line = parser.ReadFields();
        }
        catch (MalformedLineException ex)
        {
            // log ex.Message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what I'm looking for. I need a library that given a schema can validate the file. Things like date formats, not null, ranges, currencies, reg exp, etc.